# 404 error sporadically occurs on umbraco area module with angular

Tags: angularjs, umbraco, area

I have an Umbraco project with an Area section configured with Angular.
I use the Plugins to integrate the Area with the use of package.manifest like this:

[image]

Into edit.controller.js, I have this script:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("umbraco")
   .controller('Administration.AdministrationTree.EditController', function administrationEditController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
      //set a property on the scope equal to the current route id
      $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
      $scope.url = "";
      $scope.canShow = false;

      $scope.showIframe = function () {
         if ($scope.url === "") {
            return false;
         }

         return true;
      };

      $scope.canShow = false;

      if (!$scope.id) {
         return;
      }

      $http.get('/umbraco/backoffice/administration/CustomSection/GetUrl/?node=' + $scope.id)
         .success(function (data) {

            $scope.url = JSON.parse(data);
            $scope.canShow = $scope.url;
         });
   });
```

When I run the project and click on any node in this area, I receive most of the time a 404 error like if the page was not exist. I say "most of the time" because 1 out of 10, it works and the page is displayed.

However, if I put a breakpoint in the javascript function below and I click on any node and resume the javascript after the breakpoint was hitting, the node related html page is displayed correctly.

Anybody know why when I put a breakpoint, Umbraco or Angular are able to resolve 100% of the time the page but not when I don't have any breakpoint in this function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really hate to answer my own questions but after 2 weeks without answers and a lot of reflections on my side, I finally found a solution to this problem.

What was causing the problem of out synching between Umbraco and Angular was due to the $http.get query which is asynchronous with Angular (no other choice I think) and after a response from the server to get a valid URL, the $scope object was not able to talk to Umbraco to redirect to the valid URL.

On my asp.net MVC controller, the GetUrl function was trying to get a valid URL doing a query to the database where I keep a structure of nodes which correspond to a tree displayed to the user. This is a slow process and the time required to respond to the HTTP get request was too long the vast majority of the time.

Here is my solution to this problem:

```
'use strict';

var myCompany = myCompany || {};
myCompany.myProject = myCompany.myProject || {};

myCompany.myProject.controller = (function (parent){
   parent.urls = {};

   function loadUrls () {
      $.get('/umbraco/backoffice/administration/CustomSection/GetUrls')
         .success(function (data) {
            parent.urls = data;
         });
   };

   loadUrls();

   return parent;
})({});

angular.module("umbraco")
   .controller('Administration.AdministrationTree.EditController', function administrationEditController($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
      //set a property on the scope equal to the current route id
      $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
      $scope.url = "";
      $scope.canShow = false;

      $scope.showIframe = function () {
         if ($scope.url === "") {
            return false;
         }

         return true;
      };

      $scope.canShow = false;

      if (!$scope.id) {
         return;
      }

      var url = myCompany.myProject.controller.urls.find(function (element) {
         return element.Key == $scope.id;
      });

      if (url) $scope.url = url.Value;

      $scope.canShow = $scope.url;
   });
```

Note in this case that I have an iffe function which query the server to build an array of all my URLs from the backoffice and then when Angular need a redirection, I search directly from the array.

The iffe function is calling only once when the user enters in the backoffice section which I think is nice because the structure behind rarely changes.

I'm not sure if it's a hack or the valid way to do the thing due to my lack of experience with Angular but it works like a charm.